# Why does the one-to-many mapping in EF Core only work in one direction?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new to EF, and I am having trouble understanding an aspect of how EF Core works.

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlServer($"Data Source=LAIN\\MSSQLSERVER01;Initial Catalog=PlayDb;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Intent=ReadWrite;Multi Subnet Failover=False");
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public List<Post> Posts { get; } = new();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Url={this.Url}; Posts={string.Join(",", this.Posts.Select(x => x.ToString()))}";
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Title={this.Title}; Content={this.Content}; Linked Blog URL={this.Blog.Url}";
    }
}
```

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;

using var db = new BloggingContext();

void Create()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Inserting a new blog");

    var b1 = new Blog { Url = "qwe" };
    var b2 = new Blog { Url = "asd" };
    var p1 = new Post { Title = "post about qwe", Content = "1234" };
    b1.Posts.Add(p1);

    db.Add(b1);
    db.Add(b2);
    db.Add(p1);
    db.SaveChanges();
}

// Read
void Read()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Reading the database.");

    foreach (var x in db.Blogs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    }

    foreach (var x in db.Posts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    }
}

void Delete()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Deleting the tables.");

    db.Blogs.ExecuteDelete();
    db.Posts.ExecuteDelete();
}

Read();
```

After seeding the database, here is what it prints out after I run it:

```
Url=qwe; Posts=
Url=asd; Posts=
Title=post about qwe; Content=1234; Linked Blog URL=qwe
```

What is happening is that the single `Post` object links to the `Blog` one, but not vice versa. I find this really confusing because I'd have expected this to work both ways. Shouldn't the `qwe` blog's posts be printed like this?

What am I missing?

Comment: [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)

Answer (score 1):

```cs
void Read()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Reading the database.");

    foreach (var x in db.Blogs.Include(x => x.Posts))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    }

    foreach (var x in db.Posts)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    }
}
```

```
Reading the database.
Url=qwe; Posts=Title=post about qwe; Content=1234; Linked Blog URL=qwe
Url=asd; Posts=
Title=post about qwe; Content=1234; Linked Blog URL=qwe
```

What I was missing is the concept of **loading**. I needed to instruct it to load the posts explicitly using the `.Include(x => x.Posts)` expression. EF Core does not load all the structures by default for the sake of efficiency.

Comment: Incidentally, I found this answer in the [very first video](https://youtu.be/Fo8VEtIjA5I?list=PLQB-TSatJvw4T7mQneItRgsemyjMMYRNk&t=963) of this Youtube playlist.